# Create Clustered Column Chart

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts, listobject

I am trying to record a macro that select the data from a listobject and creates a clustered column chart. When I record the macro, I choose the chart, there are two options for clustered column charts. I choose the chart that has the header row from the listobject set as the x axis.

However, when I run the macro the chart appears as the second option for clustered column charts which I do not want.

How do I create a chart so that the header row from my listobject is set as the x axis on my chart?

Comment: Can you share the recorded macro that creates the incorrect chart? (Edit your question and insert it there)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.